# Organize font according to their font family

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I know in Adobe Air it is possible to get list of all the font installed in user machine through Font.enumerateFonts(true); but how can i organize this font list with their respective font family (e.g "Arial":"bold, italic, regular, bold italic")? is their any possible way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding u like to sort font by it's style. Default it is sort by fontName.

Here following way you can do it:

```
var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true);
fonts.sortOn("fontStyle", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
```